# A question on communication system without modulation

Tags: digital-communications, lte

I know that these sort of platforms are strict and you need to have an idea of what you are doing before asking a question. I am not really that knowledgeable about signal processing though I have an idea that I would like to try out an idea that is related to signal processing.

I would like to design a system where the base station assigns the UE the frequency range in which it can communicate at. For example the UE can be allowed to transmit signals between 1920 MHz to 1930Hz, so the bandwidth is 10MHz.

The user equipment then sends signal of random frequencies between the specified range. No modulation (QAM, 16QAM etc) will be done, the signals won't carry any useful information. The transmitted signals are separated by a guard period. The base station is supposed to receive these signals and record their frequencies.

This is a little practical exercise that I would like to try out.

Could someone explain to me how I could start approaching this? What software and hardware resources are needed? What aspects about this system should I know? I know that I will need an SDR and some antennas.

Thank you.

Comment: What is UE?????

Comment: @DilipSarwate It stands for "user equipment" in the parlance of the 3GPP -- a phone, a laptop, etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_equipment

Comment: Since UE is not universally understood, please _edit your question_ to either just type out "user equipment" in place of "UE", or to define the term.

Comment: This question is self-contradictory.  If your transmitted signals can be received, and the transmit frequency determined, then they _do_ carry information -- to wit, the transmitted frequency.  If the transmitter assigns meanings to the various frequencies, then -- congratulations -- you've reinvented frequency-shift keying, or multi-tone keying, depending on whether you just transmit at one frequency at a time.  What are you _really_ trying to do here?

Answer (score 2):

The specific experiment you describe is not particularly difficult as these things go, but it's far from trivial!

I would start by brushing up on DSP concepts with a book such as "SDR for engineers" from Artech House, and learning gnuradio in parallel. Once you have a better idea of what you need, decide on hardware (the ADALM-PLUTO is the cheapest decent SDR that can transmit as well as receive). Then, start implementing your system. Many specific problems will come up, so make sure to have a list of forums and mailing lists where to seek help -- including this site.